# ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDrive API error No variants found for ':app'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, shimmer

I have a basic application that renders a 3d model. Now I need to connect to the Shimmer Inertial Measurement Units via bluetooth. I have added the ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver folder to my libs folder in the root directory of my project and added the following to my build.gradel file and my settings. gradle file.

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.modelrenderinga4'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.modelrenderinga4"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'

    //Filament for rendering model
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-android:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:gltfio-android:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.14.0'

    //For shimmer
    implementation files('libs/ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver/ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver.aar')
    implementation (group: 'com.shimmersensing', name: 'ShimmerBluetoothManager', version:'0.9.42beta') {
        exclude group: 'io.netty'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons.math'
    }
    implementation (group: 'com.shimmersensing', name: 'ShimmerDriver', version:'0.9.138beta') {
        exclude group: 'io.netty'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons.math'
    }


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

**settings.gradle (Project Level)**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        //shimmmer
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://shimmersensing.jfrog.io/artifactory/ShimmerAPI'
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "ModelRenderingA4"
include ':app'
```

I tried using Java 17 and Java 12, and I'm running into the following error when syncing gradle: No variants found for ':app'. I've added a screenshot of my project structure

The dependencies related to shimmer were obtained through online searching. Is there any compatibility issues or anything I'm missing which is causing this error.

Comment: Try adding this line `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])` to build.gradle (:app)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide help. I've added that line to my build.gradle (:app) file but im still getting the same error.